# How to use Jenkins Multi Branch Pipeline when Build process needs more than one repository

Tags: jenkins

I would like to create Jenkins Multi branch pipeline to support build that needs more than one repository. 
I have a project that contain two repositories: Frontend and backend. 
Currently I have build pipeline that make checkout to the repositories and upload the build to Nexus. These repositories are hard coded in the Jenkins script, Jenkins script is part of the build configuration, not included in the repository.
As I would like to have the option to choose branches source other than the hard coded, I would like to use Multi branch pipeline and move the Jenkins file to repository.
In order to do so I need to have Jenkins file in repository.
On which repository I need to put the file? Frontend? Backend? Both?
If I open the directory of the Multi branch pipeline I can see all branches from Front End and Backend. I need to choose one the make the build, but there is no meaning to choose one branch, for build I need to choose frond end and backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more control like being able to checkout multiple repositories, better disable the default checkout as show below :

```
pipeline {
  agent ... 
  options {
    skipDefaultCheckout true
  }
```

Then perform checkouts further in the pipeline, depending on your needs.

Or better, have a complete separate pipeline not linked to those repositories.

Then do a manual checkout